# Welcome Discord Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so i tried adding an embed message in the welcome message and as i pressed `npm run` it stated that there was an error the error is stated below. file is named as welcome.py

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#2f3136')
        .setTitle('Welcome to miyoko.')
        .setImage("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/891480598680600608/893855953831743508/image0.jpg")
        .setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/891338757972840458/603efa60b46e5dd8b09aafeaf8167c5c.webp")
        .setDescription('<:asc_bhrttt:893064714735726622> <#892951925270642739> \n <:ra_xheart01:893064647698178069> <#892953158299582484> \n <:ra_xheart02:893065191170924544> <#892954010993164308')

    member.guild.channels.get('891480598680600608').send(exampleEmbed);
})
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/welc-hyewon/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/runner/welc-hyewon/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/runner/welc-hyewon/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/welc-hyewon/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)H
```

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: done adding it please take a look!

Comment: Looks like `node index.js` is failing. Do you have the file reachable and named accordingly?

Comment: i named the file welcome.js soo i think it is

Comment: Do you have an index.js?

Comment: yup ill edit the question again wait

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem related to discord.js. These are node errors

Comment: You don't have the required node.js version. You need at least 16.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What node.js version are you using? It looks like you are using an old node.js version.
Use `node -v` to check.
You can download the latest node.js version here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/